# Java Canvas Class does not paint

Tags: java, canvas, radio-button, draw, paint

I wanted to write a program, that checks which RadioButton is selected(circle, filled circle or rectangle). Then the user clicks somewhere on the canvas field. It should recognize the coordinates where the user clicked and then draw whatever is selected as radio button at that position.

Sadly it doesn't do that. In fact my code does not even reach the "ActionListener". I checked the code already like 5 times and did some testing but still could not figure it out.

Hope you can help

```
public class Optionen extends JFrame {
MeinCanvas drawspace = new MeinCanvas();
ButtonGroup btngrp= new ButtonGroup();
int xpos, ypos;

public Optionen(String titel) {
    super(titel);  
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,20,20));
    JRadioButton opt1 = new JRadioButton();
    JRadioButton opt2 = new JRadioButton();
    JRadioButton opt3 = new JRadioButton();
    opt1.setActionCommand("Kreis"); //circle
    opt1.setActionCommand("Scheibe"); // filled circle
    opt1.setActionCommand("Rechteck"); //rectangle
    opt1.setText("Kreis");
    opt2.setText("Scheibe");
    opt3.setText("Rechteck");
    btngrp.add(opt1);
    btngrp.add(opt2);
    btngrp.add(opt3);
    panel.add(opt1);
    panel.add(opt2);
    panel.add(opt3);


    add(drawspace);
    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optionen fenster = new Optionen("Optionswindow");
    fenster.pack();
    fenster.setSize(450,500);
    fenster.setResizable(true);
    fenster.setVisible(true);
}

class MeinCanvas extends Canvas {
class MeinMausAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousPressed(MouseEvent e) {
        xpos = e.getX();
        ypos = e.getY();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this);
        repaint();
    }
}

public MeinCanvas() {
    addMouseListener(new MeinMausAdapter());
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setForeground(Color.orange);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    ButtonModel btnmdl= m_formauswahl.getSelection();
    String label = btnmdl.getActionCommand();
    int w = (int) (Math.random()*300);
    int h = (int) (Math.random()*300);
    if (label.equals("Kreis"))
        g.drawOval(xpos, ypos, w, w);
    if (label.equals("Scheibe"))
        g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, w, h);
    if (label.equals("Rechteck"))
        g.drawRect(xpos, ypos, w, h);
}
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(300,300);
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return getMinimumSize();
}
}
}
```

Eclipse tells me that the code is fine, but whenever I run the program, it instantly throws exceptions. Here is the dump:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at kapitel10.Optionen$MeinCanvas.paint(Optionen.java:79)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems:

1. Don't mix AWT (Canvas) components with Swing (JFrame) components. Stick with all Swing components.
2. Instead draw as described in the Swing painting tutorials -- in the `paintComponent` override method of a JPanel.
3. Don't forget to call the super method in your override.
4. Most of your code shouldn't even be in a painting method but rather in your MouseListener code. You may be getting the NPE because the JRadioButton hasn't yet been selected when the GUI first draws itself.
5. In your MouseListener, get the ButtonModel, **check that it's not null**, then get the actionCommand, then change the state of a class field that is used by the paintComponent method, and then call `repaint()`.

---

**Edit**

Also it's not `mousPressed` but `mousePressed` !!
You must use the `@Override` annotation before all overridden methods to avoid this sort of error.

```
  class MeinMausAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

     @Override  // this will cause a compiler error
     public void mousPressed(MouseEvent e) { // until you fix this spelling!
        ButtonModel btnmdl = btngrp.getSelection();
        if (btnmdl == null) {
           System.out.println("btn model is null");
           return;
        }
        actionCmd = btnmdl.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(actionCmd);
        xpos = e.getX();
        ypos = e.getY();
        // JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this);
        repaint();
     }
  }
```

---

Also: you must set your JRadioButton's actionCommands explicitly. You're only doing this for **one** JRadioButton -- look at your code carefully.

Comment: I've seen people use `Canvas` with `JFrame` in games quite often. You shouldn't use AWT with Swing cause one is heavyweight and one is lightweight respectively, although, I've also heard that JFrames were heavyweight. Could you please explain?

Comment: Could you please punch me hard in the face? Thanks a lot Hovercraft Full Of Eels !!! Sometimes I feel retarded. My code is working perfectly now! I was scared at first that it will take me the whole weekend to finally get it running. I am still a beginner. Thanks a lot again !